# "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'parentNode')" when Using arrow keys to navigate through a list Dropdown.Item under Dropdown.Menu

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

This code is part of making a custom text auto fill component.

I create a list of <Dropdown.Item> components under a <Dropdown.Menu> component. This Dropdown menu should only appear when there are valid 'options' to display under a text box. If I tab to the dropdown menu once rendered, and try to use the arrow keys to navigate through the list, I get the following error.

`caught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'parentNode')`

```
const renderOptions = () => {
        if (textValue === '') {
            return;
        }

        const validOptionsList = options
            .filter((option) => {
                if (option.toLowerCase().trim().includes(textValue.toLowerCase().trim())) {
                    return (option);
                }
            })
            .map((option) =>
                <Dropdown.Item
                onClick={() => handleClick(option)}>
                    {option}
                </Dropdown.Item>);

        if (validOptionsList.length === 0) {
            return;
        }

        return (
            <div>
                <Dropdown>
                <Dropdown.Menu style={{width: textInputRef?.current?.clientWidth}}
                               show={validOptionsList.length > 0}>
                    {validOptionsList}
                </Dropdown.Menu>
                </Dropdown>
            </div>)
    }

 return (
        <div>
            <Form.Control
                style={{width: width}}
                ref={textInputRef}
                type={'text'}
                placeholder={placeHolder}
                onChange={e => setTextValue(e.target.value)}
                value={textValue}
                maxLength={255}
            />
            {renderOptions()}
        </div>
    )
```

I either need to find a way to have the arrow keys navigate through the `Dropdown.Item` components, or disable the arrow keys from trying to navigate through these components.

I have tried to add an event listener to listen for the arrow key presses and tried to use `preventDefault()` and `stopPropagation()` with caught events, but this did not work.